# Why I should not study embedded categories?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, philosophy, functors

In my lecture course of representation theory of $K$-algebras, we embedded the category of $A$-modules (where $A$ is an associative unital $K$-algebra) into the category of $K<X_i|i\in I>$-modules (where $K<X_i|i\in I>$ is the free $K$-algebra generated by $X_i, i\in I$). Then we studied for a time only the latter category. 
The embedding was full (i.e. injective on objects, bijective on homsets).
But I think it is not always good to study the ''larger category'', since the smaller one can lead us to a much stronger theory for that special case (but not every general). Two good examples would be:

1) Fully embedding the category of fields into the category of commutative unital rings.
On one side we get the strong Galois Theory, on the other side we get the usual theory, which is taught in Commutative Algebra (spectrum, Dimension Theory, Modul Theory,...). The striking thing here is, that the theory of Commutative Algebra is in some sense ''trivial for fields'', although it is much more general. 
Like $Spec(K)=\{(0)\}$ and therefore lots of theorems are trivial for the case of a field.

2) Embedding the category of all vector spaces (not $K$-vector spaces, all vectorspaces! I think this should be a category, if not the concept is the same) into the category of all modules. 
The first leads to the usual vector space theory with all its power. The latter is much weaker (in some sense), but much more general.

Would you say that it is not always good to look at a more general case (here the larger category) or something like: we should first study the ''easier cases'' well, before attacking the more general one? 
It is kind of confusing, since we could consider the category of all modules over free algebras, which can be embedded into the category of all modules over algebras. If we consider it like this, then the easier case would be the category of all modules over free algebras and not vice versa (like in the embedding in the first sentence).

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for here.  There is no general rule that tells us when we have added just enough structure to some category to make for a rich theory without unnecessary limitations.  It's a judgment call, at best.

Comment: A thing to be aware of is that if you embed a category $\mathcal C$ inside another category $\mathcal D$, it is possible that some constructions which come from universal properties exist both in $\mathcal C$ and in $\mathcal D$, but different. For instance: the coproduct of abelian groups in the category $\operatorname{Grp}$ is not the coproduct of the same goups in the category $\operatorname{Ab}$, although the embedding is full. This comes from the fact that the coproduct is described by its behaviour with respect to all other objects.

Comment: That is a very useful information Gae. S. Thank you!

Comment: You should learn how to format equations in mathjax, see here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference